# Building a pre-desc row table on My-Sql to make faster searching query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make more faster searching query on My-Sql database.

I have 800,000 rows in `BOOKMARK` table.

when I run with this query

```
SELECT * FROM `BOOKMARK` WHERE `topic` = 'Apple'
Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 501 total, Query took 0.0008 sec)
```

It's damn fast!

I have total point for each rows and want to find good one first.

```
SELECT * FROM `BOOKMARK` WHERE `topic` = 'Apple' ORDER BY total DESC
Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 501 total, Query took 0.4770 sec) [b_total: 9.211558703193814 - 1.19674062055568]
```

It's now 0.5 seconds!!

This is a huge problem for me.

Here are the table information.

```
* There are 20,000 different topics in this table.
* total number exist between 0-10
* The server calculate total points once a day.
```

I was thinking that if the table is ordered by total number for each topics, the search query doesn't have to include 'ORDER BY total DESC'.

It will save a lot of time, if the table check the orders once a day.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: Please let me know if you don't understand my question.

Comment: Do you have table indexed by topic, total in desc order? `create index idx_x on bookmark (topic, order desc) `

Comment: @danihp is it something like this? CREATE INDEX idx
ON bookmark (total DESC)

Comment: sorry, my mistake, replace 'order' by 'total' in my previous query and you get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple.

I use PhpMyAdmin and changed the setting on Operations menu.

like below image.

[image]

After this,

```
SELECT * FROM `BOOKMARK` WHERE `topic` = 'Apple'
```

I ran this query and showed me the result with total value DESC.

Perfect!!